# SVG Height not adjusting with aspect ratio

Tags: html, css, svg

Used one svg image in the div with the width 50px, but in IE11 , SVG height is coming as 150px. It should have been 50px X 50px . width 50px is applying correctly not the height. Any suggestion ,

```css
.svg-cont{
  width:50px
}
img{
  max-width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="svg-cont">
  <img src="http://imgh.us/google-plus-hvr.svg" alt="" />
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for any help. codepen: http://codepen.io/shmdhussain/pen/YZmrOq

Comment: What about `preserveAspectRatio` attribute in SVG file ?

Comment: @dejauneetdebleu: The issue I solved after reading some articles about SVG, this one from Sara https://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/08/19/making-svgs-responsive-with-css/  helps. setting the width:100% to image solving the issue in IE9-11

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Issue is solved after setting the width:100% to the image tag . issue resolved pen codepen: http://codepen.io/shmdhussain/pen/XMvzWv

```css
.svg-cont{
  width:50px
}
img{
  max-width:100%;
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="svg-cont">
  <img src="http://imgh.us/google-plus-hvr.svg" alt="" />
</div>
```

reference: https://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/08/19/making-svgs-responsive-with-css/